# How can I generate a valid WCF proxy for a service that has a period in the message types?

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl, rpc, period

I am interfacing with a web service I have no control over and it has messages (input/output) and actions that contain periods (.)

When svcutil generates the proxy, it includes:

```
[MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="The.Request",...)]
public partial class TheRequest
{ ... }

[MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="The.Response",...)]
public partial class TheResponse
{ ... }
```

which model the WSDL:

```
<wsdl:message name="The.Request">
    <wsdl:part name="Input" type="tns:InputType" />
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="The.Response">
    <wsdl:part name="Return" type="tns:Return" />
</wsdl:message>
```

When the code is run, I get an error message:

`RPC Message TheRequest in operation DoIt has an invalid body name Input. It must be TheRequest`

Stack Trace:

at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.OperationReflector.EnsureMessageInfos()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.EnsureMessageInfos()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.Reflector.OperationReflector.get_Request()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.CreateFormatter()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IOperationBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription description, ClientOperation proxy)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BindOperations(ContractDescription contract, ClientRuntime proxy, DispatchRuntime dispatch)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildProxyBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, BindingParameterCollection& parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.BuildChannelFactory(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, Boolean useActiveAutoClose)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateFactory()

....

I can't find a way to change the validation to accept the message name.

Can anyone clue me in on what to do or, at least, point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I'm running into the same problem and also can't find a solution.  As I am consuming a SOAP service that I didn't create, I can't change anything on the service side.